# Does not have PHP gareth/php-ews mail body

Tags: php, exchangewebservices

I am trying to make the connection with the garethp/php-ews PHP library, but when I try to obtain the body of the email it does not bring me anything.

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use garethp\ews\API\Type;
use garethp\ews\MailAPI;

$api = MailAPI::withUsernameAndPassword('server', 'username', 'password');

$items = $api->getMailItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item instanceof Type\MessageType) {
        $emailId = $item->getItemId()->getId();
        $subject = $item->getSubject();
        echo "EmailId: " . $emailId . "<br>";
        echo "Subject: " . $subject . "<br>";
        $body = $item->getBody();
        echo "Body: " . $body . "<br>";
    }
}
```

I would like to have the body of the email with this library, I don't know if there is another way or if I'm missing something

Comment: Where/how are you actually checking or outputting the data from `$body`? There's nothing in this code which would do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't understand the question very well, so should you check something additional in the code?
since when I bring the subject and the email Id it brings it up correctly, the thing is only with the body of the email, it doesn't bring me or show anything.

Comment: Ok thanks. It's clearer now. If you replace `echo "Body: " . $body . "<br>";` with `var_dump($body);` what do you see? Please paste the exact output into a comment here or into your question